# Filter in FIlter Widget

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I need to expand the Filter Widget with filter options ie filter in the filtered Multiple Select

The Model

```
class OrganizationSelection(models.Model):
    "A set of companies bundled."
    organizations = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, verbose_name=_('organizations'))
    title = TitleField(unique=True, verbose_name=_('title'))
```

The Admin

```
class OrganizationSelectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'enabled', 'locked')
    list_filter = ('enabled', 'locked')
    search_fields = ('title', 'comment')
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {
            'widget': admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
                    OrganizationSelection._meta.get_field('organizations').verbose_name, False)
        },
    }
```

The widget shows a list of organisations:

[image]

What i want is to be able to click on active or inactive on top of the widget to filter the items like the image below.

(This 'can' be done with Ajax Filtered Fields but there is little/no support and no documentation about Ajax Filtered Fields)

[image]

Comment: I'm now using raw_id_fields which shows a popup window with all organizations and the filters. But how can I select more than one organization each time.